# automate sshpass when server is asking a "yes/no" question

Tags: server, ssh, sshpass

I have this small script for connecting to new machines I don't have ssh-key to:

```
function my_ssh () {
    ip=$1
    optional_cmd=$2

    ssh -o "BatchMode yes" user_name@$ip exit > /dev/null 2>&1

    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "1st time connection - adding key to authorized keys list"
        sshpass -p "secret_password" ssh-copy-id user_name@$ip
    fi

    echo $optional_cmd
    ssh -X user_name@$ip $optional_cmd
}
```

This works weel for servers that either have my ssh-key, or only ask for a password in order to use ssh-copy-id. However, some servers require a "yes/no" after the following question:

> **The authenticity of host 'A.B.C.D ()' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:****.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?**

How can I add a "yes" string echoed into the server question stdin and then use the sshpass?

*ps, I went over the sshpass code from [github](https://github.com/kevinburke/sshpass) but it doesn't seem `sshpass` is designed for something like this. I think I can modify it to suite my needs, but I prefer using a normal Linux mechanism if possible*

Comment: use `ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ...`

Comment: cool! that works, but if that option wouldn't have worked (because of a tweaked ssh server) would it still be possible to mimic this behaviour?

Comment: that's ssh *client* side options. would not be impacted by ssh server side conf.

Comment: @pynexj You should expand that comment into an actual answer :)

Comment: @pynexj oh, my mistake. But the question stands. What if my client had a question not affected by -Strict...?

Comment: then you need to use utils like [tag:expect] or [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) (Expect for Shells).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP's question about entering "yes" on the ECDSA key fingerprint prompt, and I would only advise this for localhost SSHds - never in anything more than an experimental docker container setup, you can do the following:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  username@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 'whoami'
```

A use case? You could have a `nobody` user that is the only user who is allowed to password-SSH into a machine (all other users are set to require keys). You could then just get some system info you need, say, as you experiment with orchestration.

```
sshpass -p 'meminfo' ssh \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  meminfo@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 "egrep 'Mem|Cache|Swap' /proc/meminfo"
```

The result would be something like this.

```
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
meminfo@127.0.0.1's password: 
SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
SSHPASS read: 

MemTotal:       16369628 kB
MemFree:          683412 kB
MemAvailable:    8847748 kB
Cached:          6544572 kB
SwapCached:          460 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2071928 kB
```

Then you can `nmap` a cluster or Pis (or docker containers) on your LAN and then automate checking how they are doing without adding NodeJS or Python or a health API service.

If you're finished experimenting and want to clean up those rubber-stamped ECDSA fingerprints, you can run:

```
ssh-keygen -f "~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[127.0.0.1]:2222"
```

**Warning:** I must remind everyone that *even* the above with a `nobody` user can be dangerous if they find some privileged command that has the `suid` bit set - `nobody`s could still run as root!

Comment: please try to keep your eyes on the ball, your -o is passed to ssh **NOT** to sshpass, not even close the same thing:  sshpass -vvv -p password ssh -p 2222 root@target.host 
SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword" 
SSHPASS read: The authenticity of host '[target.host]:2222 ([X.X.X.X]:2222)'  can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ... as you can see stupid error is generated by sshpass, NOT by ssh, and also **with ssh but without sshpass is working very well** and host is saved in know_hosts, also sshpass doesn't know -o option

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by ading this two lines:

```
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

seems like sshpass is actually reading that file instead of having an -o option

Comment: It's not `sshpass` reading this file, it's `ssh` itself. These are legit options to `ssh`. The only job of `sshpass` is to input password into `ssh`, it does nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround:

```
list.txt
vm1.example.com
vm2.example.com
vm3.example.com
...

for i in $(cat list.txt); do timeout 1 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$i; done
for i in $(cat list.txt); do ssh-copy-id -i user@$i; done

ssh user@vm1.example.com -- no pass
```